# Face detection using Android camera.?

Tags: android, api, apk, face-detection, vision

Is it possible to scan a passport image using mobile camera and save his details  and later detect that person using an Android mobile camera and fetch his details ?(Face detection)

Comment: Did you try my answer @AjithKalyan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you to use [OpenCV Recognition](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html) API.

This API can let you save face data of a person and then use it to match with the new face data that you can get.

There are two ways to go about it

1. Use OpenCV for Android
2. Use JavaCV

OpenCV for Android is more fully supported than JavaCV. Follow Google's instructions to install Eclipse, the Android SDK and NDK (don't forget the NDK!)

Afterwards, [follow this tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html) to install openCV. Try out the sample applications.

Alternatively, you can try using JavaCV instead of OpenCV for Android. This means you won't need to setup the Android NDK. It also means you won't need to write any C++. I didn't try this. But I suspect it is easier.

The downside is: it doesn't support everything OpenCV does.

Comment: Thank you for the information, I develop apps in Android studio, can I use it in that too ?

Comment: Yes, sure all the way to go, Cheers :)